# Is there to way to choose how fields in pydantic look like depends on value from constructor

Tags: python, validation, pydantic

I want to choose a figure of the fields of pydantic model depends on bool value. This value can't be in the response schemat. I tried to do this like below

```
    class HbdExchangeRate(BaseModel):
        if not self.legacy:
            base: AssetHive | AssetHbd
            quote: AssetHive
        else:
            base: LegacyAssetHbd | LegacyAssetHive
            quote: LegacyAssetHive
        def __init__(self, legacy, **kwargs):
            super.__init__(legacy, **kwargs)
            self.base = hbd_exchange_rate['base']
            self.quote = hbd_exchange_rate['quote']
            self.legacy = legacy
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and clearer to just define two distinct models and have a factory function that returns an instance of either of them depending on an additional `legacy` parameter?

Comment: Probably would be, i used this solution in other part of this project, i wanted to include all things i need to one class but you’re right it would become too unclear. Thanks